# Distro agnostic init script dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, debian, centos, rhel, init-script

I'm trying to write an init script which will be able to handle basic dependencies (for example, It has to be started (just) before MySQL service starts). Is there a distro agnostic way to write such a script? And if not, how many version of the init script would there have to be to cover Ubuntu, Debian and RHEL/Centos (5.x and 6.x)?

Comment: Good luck. This is why most upstreams don't ship init scripts. When everyone is on systemd and upstart, the init script nightmare will be over. If you are going "distro-agnostic", you won't even be able to rely on dependencies via LSB headers (RHEL 5 in your example won't use it).

Comment: Rephrasing @jordanm: it's for the distro maintainer(s) to supply integration of various packages. Init scripts are one of the key parts.

Comment: As said by @jordanm, make a "init system agnostic" dependency check (openrc, systemd, upstart, sysinit...) would be to much pain...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [LSBInitScripts](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It may not answer your question directly, but this is exactly the kind of problems being solved by automation systems like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and others.

Apps are packaged into generic reusable modules that you can use to configure a machine regardless of the distro it's running.